# VS 2015 with F# cannot build the project, because dll is used by another process

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2015

I'm having problem with F# project build on Visual Studio 2015. When trying to build it several times during a single coding session, what I'm receiving is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\fsc.exe -o:obj\Debug\[project_name.dll] -g --debug:full --noframework --define:DEBUG --define:TRACE --doc:bin\Debug\[project_name.XML] --optimize- --tailcalls-  --target:library --warn:3 --warnaserror:76 --vserrors --LCID:1033 --utf8output --fullpaths --flaterrors --subsystemversion:6.00 --highentropyva+ --sqmsessionguid:bf374a59-aa1c-49c7-bd0e-2ca680563929 --[list of referenced dlls and files to build]
>
> ...
>
> warning MSB3026: Could not copy "obj\Debug\[project_name_dll]" to "bin\Debug\[project_name_dll]". Beginning retry 10 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\[project_name_dll]' because it is being used by another process.
>
> error MSB3027: Could not copy "obj\Debug\[project_name_dll]" to "bin\Debug\[project_name_dll]". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.
>
> error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\[project_name_dll]" to "bin\Debug\[project_name_dll]". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\[project_name_dll]' because it is being used by another process.

It turned out that the process, which is blocking project's dll to be replaced, is `devenv` itself. I'm running a single instance of Visual Studio, and I'm trying to rebuild a project, that has no debugger attached.

Any tips, how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried just deleting your bin folders manually?

Comment: I cannot, because explorer is telling me, that project .dll file is already open in Visual Studio.

Comment: Well then you should try closing VS and then deleting the bin folders manually.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a solution. I want to understand and fix a cause, not the symptoms. Requirement of closing entire IDE and manually removing bin folder each time I want to build a project can hardly be considered a valid way of work.

Comment: Have you used a program to check what has the lock or locks? Typically in this situation what you think and what is real are different. See: [Find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows)

Comment: Of interest: ["File is being used by another process" error](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/file-being-another-process-error-71003.aspx)

Comment: Searching with Google for `Beginning retry 10 in 1000ms` is turning up lots of different suggestions. As such you need to include more specific information in your question.

Comment: As I've written, the process blocking dll file is devenv, Visual Studio itself. I've also provided as much info, as I was able to gather.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fsi and have loaded the dlls then that is the problem. Reset your fsi session and it will clear up.